# Visual studio generating faulty projects with opencv

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

So, I am not exactly sure how to entitle this problem, but basically any new projects I create do not work.
I am using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate to use opencv 2.4.9. When I create a new project and input the sample code to load an image, it builds successfully: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxsE5.png

However, when I run the executable or debug in VS2012, it crashes/does not work properly: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxEqN.png, sometimes creating two processes of itself which cannot be killed.
Here is the sample code I used:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    if( argc != 2)
{
 cout <<" Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
 return -1;
}

Mat image;
image = imread(argv[1], IMREAD_COLOR); // Read the file

if(! image.data ) // Check for invalid input
{
    cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
    return -1;
}

namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE ); // Create a window for display.
imshow( "Display window", image ); // Show our image inside it.

waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
return 0;
}
```

I have previously made one project which is still working just fine and I have even ran the same sample code to compare - the executables are of the same size, but only the very first project works.

Now, here's how I got the very first project working:

• I first installed visual studio 2012 update 5 (not the whole thing, just the update, I know).

• I then installed visual studio 2015 community.

• I downloaded opencv 3.0.0 but couldn't get that to work with VS2015.

• I downloaded opencv 2.4.9 (because that was the version used in one of the setup tutorials at opencv.org) but still couldn't get it to work.

• I then finally downloaded VS2012 ultimate AND got opencv 2.4.9 to work on both VS2015 and VS2012.

• I then uninstalled VS2015 along with a lot of things that seemed to be unrelated.

• In turn, my projects wouldn't build on VS2012 anymore.

• I ran repair for VS2012 and my first project was working fine again. However, when I tried to create a new project, I would encounter the described problem.

Here's what I've tried so far:

• Completely reinstalling VS2012

• Installing VS2012 update 5

• Installing VS2015 community and trying to create a project there.

I understand that this may be just a huge mess, but I have not found anyone with a similar problem yet and I have no idea what to do now, so, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For VS2012 make sure you use the opencv binaries in the vc11 folder. And yes I mean vc11. vc12 = Visual Studio 2013. The 2 digit # only matches the year for vc10. And make sure you use the Debug libs & dlls for Debug builds and the Release libs & dlls for Release builds.

Comment: Yes, I've used the correct folder paths and I setup property sheets which tell VS2012 where to get libs and dlls from. I've tried to both re-use the property sheets from the working project and re-make them from scratch for new projects and since it managed to build successfully, but not produce a working executable in both cases, I am positive they are not the cause of the problem.

Comment: Make sure you have no other opencv dlls in your path.

Comment: I did; I did not touch my opencv folder since the day I extracted it. I have tried to both use an environmental variable to point towards the dlls and libs as well as to use the full path and it reaches them without any problems (when I failed to point correctly, I would get errors when trying to build). I have also tried to re-download opencv, in hopes that it got somehow corrupted and that was the cause - it was still not working. At this point, I have more or less completely reinstalled/remade everything that I used for my first working project without any success.